# Instert emoji into itunes description

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, emoji

I am an iPhone dev and I would like to know ho to insert emoji into the iTunes description of the app.

Sometimes when you read a description of the app in AppStore you can see stars, objects, dogs etc... but when you write them you are into iTunesconnect trough a browser.

How can I put the emoji into the description??

Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe best/simpler solution:

while writing down your description press Control + Command + Space in the text box. This will show the mac emoji keyboard. Just select the one you like and MAGIC !!!

Answer (score 1):

Write the description with an iPad or iPhone, including emojis in it... Send it to yourself by email, copy/paste the email body into the App Description on iTunesConnect

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing, App Store description doesnt support emojis, it will give an error upon saving.

> Description - This field contains one or more invalid characters.